# Error 1452: cannot add or update a child row en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

En MySQL tengo una tabla video y otra tabla usuario con una llave foránea en la que el valor correo de video hace referencia a correo de usuario. Y a la hora de ejecutar el sql en el que se añaden los datos a las tablas me sale el siguiente error.

> Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`gomezpenco`.`video`, CONSTRAINT `correoVideo` FOREIGN KEY (`correo`) REFERENCES `usuario` (`correo`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

La tabla usuario (los datos son inventados):

```
    INSERT INTO Usuario 
        (correo, password, nombre, apellidos, descripcion, nSubscriptores,
        imagenFondo, imagenPersonal, nick, pais)
        VALUES
        ('raquelegeagonzalez@gmail.com', '1234r', 'Raquel', 'Egea Gonzalez', 'Hago gameplays de videojuegos en internet', '4', 
        'https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fes.vecteezy.com%2Fvectores-gratis%2Ffondo-banner&psig=AOvVaw2fuFLZrx_qRVrik-ovJGKm&ust=1679570272089000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CBAQjRxqFwoTCMjrr_207_0CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAE',
        'https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.planetadelibros.com%2Fautor%2Freah%2F000048560&psig=AOvVaw1BSVd3XwhQ_FahtFULq0hx&ust=1679571128902000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CBAQjRxqFwoTCMDk6JW47_0CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAE',
        'Reah', 'España'),
        ('danielgalardolopez@gmail.com', '4367d', 'Daniel', 'Galardo Lopez', 'Me gusta hacer carreras de coches', '2', 
        'https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.freepik.es%2Ffotos%2Fbanner&psig=AOvVaw2fuFLZrx_qRVrik-ovJGKm&ust=1679570272089000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CBAQjRxqFwoTCMjrr_207_0CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAJ',
        'https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fes.dreamstime.com%2Fimagen-de-archivo-retrato-de-un-hombre-negro-joven-image7196761&psig=AOvVaw1iTmoveY7ZnshNuqVO_Yv3&ust=1679570773978000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CBAQjRxqFwoTCPjez-y27_0CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAE',
        'Dalilla', 'Francia'),
        ('pablomingorancecortes', '52387p', 'Pablo', 'Mingorance Cortes', 'Tengo un canal de youtube en el que hago reviews de dispositivos electronicos', '2',
        'https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.freepik.es%2Fvector-premium%2Fbanner-fondo-tecnologia-azul-moderno_22447672.htm&psig=AOvVaw2fuFLZrx_qRVrik-ovJGKm&ust=1679570272089000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CBAQjRxqFwoTCMjrr_207_0CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAR',
        'https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.proandroid.com%2Fquienes-somos%2F&psig=AOvVaw1I9S4Wp7bcGPLO69k18XII&ust=1679571228453000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CBAQjRxqFwoTCNCwrcW47_0CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAE',
        'Pro Android', 'España');
```

La tabla video:

```
    INSERT INTO video (IdVideo, titulo, descripcion, fecha, nVisualizaciones, meGusta, noMeGusta, monetizado, correo, url) VALUES
    (1, 
    'Martha está fría - Martha is Dead 01', 
    'Hemos vuelto al gaming! Aquí os traigo los directos resubidos y un poquito editados de Martha is Dead, un juego de terror psicológico que nos estamos pasando en directo en Twitch. Allí me encontrarás las tardes de los lunes, miércoles y viernes.',
    '2023-02-22', 800 , 2, 2, 0, 'raquelegeagonzalez@gmail.com', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i3RVX4IBTrI'),
    (2, 
    '¿Empieza el salseo? ¿Un embarazo? - Martha is Dead 02', 
    'Hemos vuelto al gaming! Aquí os traigo los directos resubidos y un poquito editados de Martha is Dead, un juego de terror psicológico que nos estamos pasando en directo en Twitch. Allí me encontrarás las tardes de los lunes, miércoles y viernes.',
    '2023-02-23', 1000 , 2, 2, 1, 'raquelegeagonzalez@gmail.com', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4qyp_579Ekw')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE correo = correo;
```

El script:

```html
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `gomezpenco`.`usuario` ;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gomezpenco`.`usuario` (
  `correo` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `apellidos` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `descripcion` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `nSubscriptores` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `imagenFondo` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `imagenPersonal` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `nick` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `pais` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`correo`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4
COLLATE = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `gomezpenco`.`video` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gomezpenco`.`video` (
  `idVideo` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `titulo` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `descripcion` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `nVisualizaciones` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `meGusta` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `noMeGusta` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `monetizado` TINYINT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `correo` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` TEXT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idVideo`),
  INDEX `correoVideo_idx` (`correo` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `correoVideo`
    FOREIGN KEY (`correo`)
    REFERENCES `gomezpenco`.`usuario` (`correo`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4
COLLATE = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. Sobre tu pregunta: ¿Cuál sql que añade qué datos en qué tablas? Está bien ver el mensaje de error completo y el contenido de las tablas para saber qué datos hay, pero no sabemos qué script te da el error que muestras. PD. Espero que sean datos de prueba y no estés mostrando información de usuarios reales :/

Comment: Los datos que aparecen son todos inventados, ya he puesto el script que tengo

Comment: Por lo que he podido comprobar, todo funciona correctamente: https://dbfiddle.uk/bH_oTm3I